# Closest date in a vector to a given date

Tags: r, date, closest

I would like to identify the closest date in a vector of given date. Let's say I have the following date vector (with 5 random dates):

```
coldate= as.Date(c("2013-08-03", "2013-09-04", "2013-09-08", "2013-09-12", "2013-11-01"));
```

Now, I want to find the closest date to `x = as.Date("2013-10-01")` inside this vector.

Here is my code :

```
> which((coldate-x) == min(coldate-x))
  [1] 1
```

The result should be 4, since the date `"2013-09-12"` is the closest. But, I have 1... What's wrong in my code?

Comment: check `neardate` in the survival package

Comment: You can also use `base::findInterval(x, coldate)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you miss an `abs` to take care of negative values:

```
which(abs(coldate-x) == min(abs(coldate - x)))
[1] 4
```

Comment: in my actual coldate vector, I have a NA. The command is now returning integer(0). How do I have to deal with this NA ?

Comment: @Henri - remove the NA's from the `min` function: `which(abs(coldate-x) == min(abs(coldate-x),na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: how would this work if x was a column of dates instead of single value?

Answer (score 11):

See also the `which.min` function:

```
R> which.min(abs(x-coldate))
[1] 4
```

Comment: While `which.min` seems like the obvious choice, the advantage of the answer by @Arun is that it will return multiple values if there are multiple minimum values. How you deal with those cases might actually be an issue in making a clean dataset, but it is something that should be considered.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @thelatemail. Now I sort coldate before using `which.min` to get the 'lower' match.

Answer (score 7):

The `which.closest()` function from the `birk` package is a simple option.

```
coldate= as.Date(c("2013-08-03", "2013-09-04", "2013-09-08", "2013-09-12", "2013-11-01"))
x = as.Date("2013-10-01")

which.closest(coldate, x)
[1] 4
```